# Azure App Service: The build failed HTTP error 500.30, where can I find the build output?

Tags: asp.net, azure

I am trying to build my app service on my azure sql db.

I set up a serveradmin and give it credentials and followed everything from the tutorial to build the connection string.

I was able to connect to my db from the tutorial project (todo app) but when I ported that into my own project and copied all the source codes, created the connection string i keep getting this upload deploy:

[image]

So I tried to build from the console and when I do it, this happens:

[image]

When I build my project locally, I get no errors. So there must be something wrong somewhere, but I wont be able to find out where.

Where can I see the build output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Kudu to view the logs -Linux/container apps: https://.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/logs/docker

You may also leverage App Service diagnostics from Azure Portal for pointers. To access App Service diagnostics, navigate to your App Service app in the Azure portal.
In the left navigation, click on Diagnose and solve problems – Checkout the tile for “Diagnostic Tools” and “Availability and Performance” > "Application Logs" title.

[image]

Comment: finding this, i realized that i changed the connection string name in program.cs. thank you!